# Laravel interface for model class attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I've been trying to implement an `Interface` based on composition with `traits` for multiple (2) models in my application.

My current solution is to manually implement a Laravel accessor for each attribute in question, since they might only exists via the database columns, and then add the accessor to the interface.

```php
interface IsStatable
{
    public function getState(): string;
}
```

```php
trait Statable
{
    public function getState(): string
    {
        return $this->state;
    }
}
```

```php
class ModelA extends Model implements IsStatable
{
    use Statable;
}
```

```php
class ModelB extends Model implements IsStatable
{
    use Statable;
}
```

```php
class SomeClass
{
    function someMethod(IsStatable $model)
    {
        echo $model->getState();
    }
}
```

I ideally want to be able to do `$model->state` directly instead of `$model->getState()` but this seems not to be possible in PHP?

Comment: You should be able to just do `$model->state`. In fact, it's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In Laravel it is, but it is not enforced through the Interface directly. I'm probably only worried whether this is appropriate in PHP.

Comment: Laravel already provides getters for you. Unless you're doing something from scratch for some reason, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: To expand on this: Every model inherits from [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html). When you write `$model->state`, your model uses the [magic  __get() function in the Model class](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___get), which in turn defers to the [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concern\HasAttributes trait's getAttribute method](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getAttribute).

Comment: [PHP interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) do not support properties, only methods.